# List loses methods when assigning as Map value

Tags: dart

I am trying to assign a List as a value to a field in a Map.

However, if I vary the types in the Map, the methods seem to be no longer available on the List.

Example:

```
  var list = [1,2];

  
  var myMap = {
    'list' : list,
    //'commentOut' : 3,    
  };

  print("${myMap['list'].runtimeType}");

  print("${myMap['list']!.length}");
```

Output

```
JSArray<int>
2
```

However, if I uncomment the line 'commentOut' : '
I get the error

```
Error: The getter 'length' isn't defined for the class 'Object'.
```

Is there a way to get this to work, or am I misunderstanding something fundamental we can't do with Maps ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do:

```dart
var list = [1,2];

var myMap = {
  'list' : list,
};
```

then the inferred type of `myMap` is `Map<String, List<int>>`.

When you instead do:

```dart
var myMap = {
  'list' : list,
  'commentOut' : 3,    
};
```

your `Map`'s values are now heterogeneous, so Dart infers the value type as the nearest common base type.  In this case, the common base type of `List<int>` and `int` is `Object`, so `myMap`'s inferred type is `Map<String, Object>`.

Consequently, static analysis tools (the Dart analyzer and the Dart compiler) know only that the *static* (known at compile-time) type of `myMap['list']` is `Object?` even though the actual *runtime* type is `List<int>`.  It therefore will be a compile-time error to attempt to directly access `List` methods on it, because calling `List` methods on an arbitrary `Object` is potentially unsafe.

You either must explicitly cast the value (`myMap['list'] as List<int>`) or disable static type checking by explicitly declaring `myMap` to be of type `Map<String, dynamic>`.

Answer (score 0):

3 is a value type, not an object type.  So the property "length" is not defined on a value type.  Even though you defined the element 'list' to get the length, it doesn't know how to handle it.